# How to see the graphical representation of emoji codepoints in R Studio Windows?

Tags: rstudio, emoji, codepoint

I have in a data frame a column with code points corresponding to emoji.
They look something like this:

```
1F1E8
```

I am using the **remoji** library, but as you can see my code points do not have **\U** in front of them, which is necessary for the methods of this library, as far as I know.
Example:

```
#This works
message (sub_emoji ("This is silly \U1f626"))

#this does not work
message (sub_emoji ("This is silly 1f626"))
```

The most I've managed to do is transform the code points to **`\\U1f626`** but it doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was trying was to paste the string `"\U"` at the beginning of the code points, but being the `\` an escape character I couldn't do it. But with some "tricks" it can be done:
I transformed all the code points to the following structure (8 hex digits):
    **`\\U000xxxxx`** (000 if 5 hex digits in the original code point)
    **`\\U0000xxxx`** (0000 if 4 hex digits in the original code point)

I have not delved into their implication ("fill" with 0), but the truth is that they work the same way, as far as I've tried:

```
message(sub_emoji("This is silly \U0001f626"))
This is silly
```

and

```
message(sub_emoji("This is silly \U1f626"))
#This is silly
```

I "filled" with 0 because I used the function `stri_unescape_unicode()` to un-escape the code points `\\Uxxxxxxxx` and get the desired result `\Uxxxxxxxx` (one `\`) to pass it to `sub_emoji()`
And this function, `stri_unescape_unicode()`, only gives this result (one `\`) if the code point has 8 hex digits, I did not study why, I only noticed this by messing around. I also noticed that if the `u` is lowercase it has another effect.
For example:

```
#it does not work
stri_unescape_unicode("\\U1F926")
#[1] NA
#Warning message: .....

stri_unescape_unicode("\\U1F926\\U1F3FB")
#[1] NA
#Warning message: .....

#it works
stri_unescape_unicode("\\U0001F926")
#[1] "\U0001f926"
stri_unescape_unicode("\\U0001F926\\U0001F3FB")
# [1] "\U0001f926\U0001f3fb"
```

A complete example:

```
em = stri_unescape_unicode("\\U0001f626")
message(sub_emoji(paste("This is silly", em)))
#This is silly 

emc = stri_unescape_unicode("\\U0001F926\\U0001F3FB")
message(sub_emoji(paste("This is silly", emc)))
#This is silly
```

Pay attention to this last emoji, it has a different skin and hair color, there is the effect of [ZWJ Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences/).